# Decrease waiting time in a Laravel application

Tags: laravel-4, developer-tools

I'm developing a PHP application written using the [Laravel](http://laravel.com) 4.1 framework. So far I only have a few MySQL queries per page, many of them are cached using the `Cache` class where possible, using a Redis server.

Currently I'm developing locally with an internal (but not `localhost`) MySQL database, using Apache 2.2.24 and PHP 5.4.17.

Using Chromes Developer Tools, I'm checking the **Network** tab to see how long the page is taking to load etc, but I'm seeing some weird results. The page spends a long time waiting for the content to be served, as you can see below:

[image: Network output]

As you can see, the *new* page takes 682ms waiting for the content to be sent back to the browser. Is there anyway that I can improve this? Why does Laravel has such a big overhead?

Apart from a custom Facade that we use to make using Entypo easier, there are no extra packages except the defaults that come with Laravel.

Does anybody know how this can be improved?

Comment: Have you use a PHP profiler to have a look what's taking up the most time? We've used NewRelic and that's been a great help to pinpoint slow SQL queries and slow code. They offer a free 14 day trial. You could also use something like XDebug.

Comment: Not as of yet, I was hoping it would be a silly configuration setting. XDebug is a PITA to get installed, but that may be the only way of really figuring this out.

Comment: I would recommend going with NewRelic if you can - even if it's just for the free trial period. It really does give some good insights - installation is simple (on Linux). The data goes back in to the new relic dashboard within 30secs or so

Comment: We've actually used them before but for a Node.js application, so our free trial has ended and we're not in a position to pay for it yet. But thanks!

Comment: If you signup again with this link: http://newrelic.com/aws you get standard for free :-)

Comment: Do I need to be using AWS?

Comment: Nope. I signed up to it through that link and used it on servers with Digital Ocean. Didn't ask me for any AWS credentials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were you I would install the [Chrome Clockwork](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp?hl=en) extension plus the [Laravel Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) package from Composer. Clockwork gives you a timeline where you can see what it is that takes so long, plus a database query tab where you can see how long time each query takes to load.

[image: screenshot of clockwork]

Happy hunting (:

Comment: This has really helped us! Although we've not really decreased the reported waiting time, I've managed to bring down the amount of queries we're executing (thanks eager-loading) and now we can log easily throughout the codebase. Thanks!